# how to calculate self discharg %/month for lithiam ion battery?

Tags: batteries

I have lithium ion battery have 
-C-rating=0.2C
-Max. capacity= 1050mAh
-Nominal voltage = 3.7V 
-Maximum voltage = 4.2V

So i want to calculate self-discharge %/month so how i calculate this suggest some stranded equation for this calculation

Comment: Is it connect to a load?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't believe the vendor's data sheet, then you don't calculate it, you measure it. Measure drop in terminal voltage month on month, and relate that approximately to capacity via the data sheet for the battery.

It varies with temperature and vendor quality. If it's not a new cell (thanks to Brian's comment) then it will vary with the use/abuse it's had during its life, depth of discharge, charge termination voltage and current, number of cycles, charge and discharge temperatures.

Comment: And age and wear/abuse (charge cycles, depth and rate of charge and discharge, on the cell, most likely.